# How to use osascript to open the Terminal App in a new window and make sure it's on the top of all other windows?

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript

I found a way to open Terminal.app very usefully as:

```
osascript -e \'tell application "Terminal" to do script "cd myfolder && ./something.sh param1"\'
```

If it were executed from a terminal window then everything is fine - at least for every case that I test. Howeer I run this command from a Node.js server because only that I can trigger a script in a terminal window. But here is the trouble: when it's executed, the Terminal window is behind my Chrome Browser.

How can this window be surely set on the top? I noticed that the window can be surely on top of other Terminal windows but how to set it on top of all other windows?

For example, the window is below Chrome and very hard to be seen:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Activate

Use the AppleScript command **activate** to [bring the Terminal.app application to the front](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14947890/bring-a-window-to-front-in-applescript):

```
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
end tell
```

Using `osascript` this becomes:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to activate'
```

Comment: Is it possible to do that in one line? Because I have to trigger this in a node.js function.

Comment: I have added an `osascript` equivalent.

Comment: `osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to activate and to do script "cd myfolder && ./something.sh param1"'` Is this correct?

Comment: Or do you mean I have to run this command twice?

Comment: The simplest solution is to run `osascript` twice from JavaScript. Once to start your script and again to bring Terminal.app to the front.

Comment: Alternative to running `osascript` twice is running it once with 2 `-e` commands, like so: `osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to activate' -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "..."'`